# Is it ok to have 8 tempdb data files on 4 logical processor?

Tags: sql-server, tempdb

I aware of the general rule of thumb, which is the no. of tempdb data files = no. of cores.

But I'm running SQL server 2016 with 4 logical processors and 8 tempdb data files.

Just wondering if this configuration will have any impact on my sql server's performance/waits. And why is it important for me to reduce the data files.

Not sure of the impact with current set up.

Answer (score 1):

I've personally never heard the advice of *creating the same number of `tempdb` data files as cores on the server*, but apparently that used to be a thing.

Per Brent Ozar, that's no longer the rule of thumb, and you generally should always just start with 8 equally sized data files, in his article [**Cheat Sheet: How to Configure TempDB for Microsoft SQL Server**](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2016/01/cheat-sheet-how-to-configure-tempdb-for-microsoft-sql-server/):

> Create 8 equally sized data files. This helps you avoid the GAM/SGAM/PFS page contention issues described in [Microsoft KB 2154845](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/troubleshoot/sql/performance/recommendations-reduce-allocation-contention). In your journey through the blogosphere, you may have read that at one point you were supposed to create one data file per core. That’s no longer the case – just start with 8, and only add more when you’re facing the page contention issues described in that KB article.